# Array Subscription: returning Reference vs proxy class method

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

While searching for methods for overloading Subscript('[]') operator for template class, I came across two different techniques.

First Technique:

Overloading the `operator []` returning pointer to the container directly, which will allow both reading value and assigning value. A sample implementation of this technique:

```
template <class T>
class X
{
    int _size;
    T *container;
public:
    X(int sz)
    {
        _size=sz;
        container=new T[sz]();
    }
    ~X()
    {

    }

    T& operator [](int indx)
    {
        return container[indx];
    }

};
```

With `main()` as:

```
X<int> sample(100);
cout<<sample[9]<<endl;
sample[9]=9;
cout<<sample[9]<<endl;
```

Output:

```
0
9
```

Second Technique:

Second technique involves declaring a proxy class and overloading the `operator =` via that class. A sample implementation of this technique:

```
template <class T>
class X
{
    int _size;
    T *container;
public:
    X(int sz)
    {
        _size=sz;
        container=new T[sz]();
    }
    ~X()
    {

    }

    class Proxy
    {
        int indx;
        X<T> &parent;
    public:
        Proxy(X<T> &p, int x) : parent(p),indx(x)
        {

        }
        void operator =(T assgn)
        {
            parent.container[indx]=assgn;
        }
        operator T const &()
        {
            return parent.container[indx];
        }
        friend class X<T>;//unnecessary line, I know!
    };
    Proxy operator[](int indx)
    {
        return Proxy(*this,indx);
    }

};
```

With same `main()` we get same output.

I personally like the second method. But, I really want to compare these two methods. What are the major functional difference of these two techniques. What advantages each of these method have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proxy-based technique you describe can be used if you want to expose a sequence of elements that are not stored as-such (requiring a conversion from and to storage) or that cannot simply be accessed by-reference. An example is std::vector < bool >: it packs eight bools in every byte (one in each bit) in storage. Storing them that way, it is not possible to return a reference to a single such bool, so the index operator returns a "proxy-object" instead to support reading and writing of the contained bools.

If you *can* return a direct reference to the stored objects, there is no real advantage to wrapping it in a proxy unless you want to restrict the assignment (only allow positive values in the container for example).

Comment: Here is another difference between 1st technique and the second one (the `Proxy` one).
When you use `auto element = createX()[3]; //createX returns a X` to retrieve elements in X (X is a temporary object) , the 1st technique give you a `T` which is a copy to the `3`rd element. 
While the `Proxy` one will gives you an `element` of `Proxy` type, and it actually refer to a temporary X object. Thus, causing undefined behavior because of dangling Proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a proxy is used when you want to return something that doesn't match the internal storage of the data. The classic example is a 2D matrix, with elements stored in a single array. If you provide an operator to return rows or columns, you need proxies. Another example is the infamous `std::vector<bool>`, where the data need not be stored as a block of `bool`, but access must return `bool` to the user.

Proxies can be used to return different "views" of segments of an internal data representation. In your example, there seems no reason to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Getting proxy objects right for most client usage is considerably trickier... for example - what if someone says:

```
tcp_peer.send_from_iterator_range(&sample[2], &sample[7+1]);
```

If `sample::operator[]` returns a temporary proxy, and that proxy doesn't carefully replace `operator&`, then the code asks for the addresses of the proxies themselves.

Some client usage just can't be supported without losing the Proxy's ability to intercept reads and/or writes to the data, for example in...

```
Container::element_type& ref = container[n];
ref = 20;
```

...the client code assumes the container's `operator[]` will yield a reference to an actual element. Any proxy returned by `operator[]` must either provide an `operator element_type&()` - handing over such a reference and taking itself out of play - or refuse to (e.g. only return a `const` reference, return a temporary by value to which a non-`const` reference can't be bound) and force edits to the client code.

So, proxy's are 95% as good when you need them, but best avoided when you don't.