# Overloading std::vector::at assignment operator

Tags: c++

I have a class which allows me to access a vectors value:

```
Class Image{
    public:
        Image(int rows, int cols): cols_(cols), rows_(rows), data_(rows*cols,0) {};
        int& at(int row, int col){
            return data_.at(col*row);
        };
    private:
        int rows_ = 0;
        int cols_ = 0;
        const int max_val_ = 255;
        std::vector<int> data_;
```

Currently this lets me perform

```
int num = image.at(row, col);
// or
image.at(row, col) = 10;
```

My question is how to I limit the values of `data_` to not allow an assignment more than `max_value_`? I.e `image.at(row,col) = 256;`

Comment: You can't do that if you return an `int&`. You would have to return a proxy object (or use an interface like `void set(int row, int col, int value)`).

Comment: Note that your index calculation is probably wrong. You want `row*cols_ + cols` for row major and `col*rows_+rows` for col major order.

Comment: Suggesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994488/what-is-proxy-class-in-c as duplicate. There is also a good discussion of benefits/drawbacks in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980171/array-subscription-returning-reference-vs-proxy-class-method.

Comment: @Timo I have noticed this but ignored for the question.

Comment: @Eljay The .at method should catch this exception, it's not exactly what I'm asking

Comment: I missed the gist.  Got it now, thank you.  I deleted my irrelevant comment.  Max's advice on having a setter interface to guarantee the caller doesn't violate the invariant is the way I'd go.

Comment: You can use uint8_t for the data type. This limits the values to 0-255.

Answer (score 0):

Like Max Langhof said, you can use a proxy object like this:

```
class AssignmentProxy
{
public:
    AssignmentProxy(int& value, int min, int max) : value_(value), min_(min), max_(max) { }
    AssignmentProxy& operator=(int value)
    {
        if (value >= min_ && value < max_)
            value_ = value;
        else 
            throw std::invalid_argument("no");

        return *this;
    }

    operator int() const noexcept
    {
        return value_;
    }

private:
    int min_, max_;
    int& value_;
};
```

The implicit conversion to `int` is questionable but justified I think, since this only a proxy that mimics an integer.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ZkLWy3) is a full example.